# Read the column specification col_types of readr::read_delim from file

Tags: r, readr

How can I read the column specification `col_types` of the `readr::read_delim` function from a file?

Instead of

```
> read_csv(file = I('varInt,varChar,varFac\n
+                    1,a,A1\n
+                    2,b,A2\n
+                    3,c,A3'),
+          col_types = cols(varInt = 'i',
+                           varChar = 'c',
+                           varFac = col_factor(levels = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3'))))
# A tibble: 3 × 3                                                                                                                                                             
  varInt varChar varFac
   <int> <chr>   <fct> 
1      1 a       A1    
2      2 b       A2    
3      3 c       A3
```

I want to do something like

```
mySpecFile <- read_csv(file = I("Variable,Spec\n
                                 varInt,i\n
                                 varChar,c\n
                                 varFac,col_factor(levels = c('A1'; 'A2'; 'A3'))"))

mySpec <- mySpecFile |> pull(Spec, Variable) |> as.list()

read_csv(file = I('varInt,varChar,varFac\n
                   1,a,A1\n
                   2,b,A2\n
                   3,c,A3'),
         col_types = mySpec)
```

But this throws: Error: Unknown shortcut: col_factor(levels = c('A1'; 'A2'; 'A3'))

So, specifying levels of factors does not work for me.

Seems to be related: [R readr col_types specified in a metadata file, specifically using custom date formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69508286/r-readr-col-types-specified-in-a-metadata-file-specifically-using-custom-date-f)

However, the `readr::read_delim` documentation says

> One of NULL, a cols() specification, or a string. See
> vignette("readr") for more details.
>
> If NULL, all column types will be inferred from guess_max rows of the
> input, interspersed throughout the file. This is convenient (and
> fast), but not robust. If the guessed types are wrong, you'll need to
> increase guess_max or supply the correct types yourself.
>
> Column specifications **created by list() or cols()** must contain one
> column specification for each column. If you only want to read a
> subset of the columns, use cols_only().
>
> Alternatively, you can use a compact string representation where each
> character represents one column:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- The `varFac` spec is a string containing `col_factor`, not a call or expression (or the results of it). We can possibly evaluate it.
- Your `varFac,col_factor(levels = c('A1'; 'A2'; 'A3'))` doesn't have a valid R expression, we need to replace `;` with `,`; this likely means the spec CSV needs to be `;`-delimited (or something other than `,`)

```r
library(readr)
mySpecFile <- read_csv2(file = I("Variable;Spec\n
                                 varInt;i\n
                                 varChar;c\n
                                 varFac;col_factor(levels = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3'))"))
# ℹ Using "','" as decimal and "'.'" as grouping mark. Use `read_delim()` for more control.
# Rows: 3 Columns: 2
# ── Column specification ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
# Delimiter: ";"
# chr (2): Variable, Spec
# ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
# ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
mySpec <- mySpecFile |>
  pull(Spec, Variable) |>
  as.list() |>
  lapply(function(z) if (nchar(z) > 1) tryCatch(eval(parse(text = z)), error = function(e) z) else z)
read_csv(file = I('varInt,varChar,varFac\n
                   1,a,A1\n
                   2,b,A2\n
                   3,c,A3'),
         col_types = mySpec)
# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#   varInt varChar varFac
#    <int> <chr>   <fct> 
# 1      1 a       A1    
# 2      2 b       A2    
# 3      3 c       A3
```

The `if (nchar(z) > 1)` is to guard against `"c"` (for `c`haracter) becoming an R function (and possibly other things). If you want more specificity, change that conditional to something else.

The `tryCatch(.., error = function(e) z)` ensures that if it is not an expression, it returns the original string.

As an alternative to using `;`-delimited text, we can quote them (or just the one string) to protect the embedded commas we need.

```r
mySpecFile <- read_csv(file = I("Variable,Spec\n
                                 varInt,i\n
                                 varChar,c\n
                                 varFac,\"col_factor(levels = c('A1', 'A2', 'A3'))\""))
```